# Not able to exclude dependency gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I need to exclude slf4j dependency from io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:5.3.0 . I have tried using

```
implementation ('io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:5.3.0') {
        exclude(group='org.slf4j',module='slf4j-loh4j12')
    }
```

But i keep getting an error

```
Cannot set the value of read-only property 'group' for DefaultExternalModuleDependency{group='io.confluent', name='kafka-schema-registry', version='5.3.0', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultExternalModuleDependency.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this. I have tried multiple way but not able to do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for `exclude()` is incorrect. You must use `:` instead of `=`. [`exclude()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude-java.util.Map-) takes a `Map` as input, thus, in Groovy DSL, it must be written as:

```
implementation ('io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:5.3.0') {
    exclude(group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12')
}
```